# Constness of Associative Arrays in D

Tags: dictionary, constants, d, associative-array, pass-by-value

As far I know maps in D have value semantics.

If so why does the second line in this example fail

```
const(uint[ubyte]) x;
uint[ubyte] y = x;
```

as

```
Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (x) of type const(uint[ubyte]) to uint[ubyte]
```

when both the key and value also have value semantics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far I know maps in D have value semantics.

D associative arrays are reference types.

Internally, they are represented as a pointer to an implementation-defined data structure. (Note that if the AA is `null`, it does not act like a reference type, as adding the first member will instantiate it.)

Comment: Hmm, I must have mistaken myself in my value-semantics tests. Now I have to go change all my `x=y` to `x=y.dup`. Thx.

Comment: Now the natural question becomes; Is there a trait to check whether a types has value or reference semantics?

Comment: Is there some utility function in Phobos that always make a new copy of a type (static, dynamic and associative arrays)? I believe using .dup in my templates because doing `y = x.dup` when x and y are both static arrays (of same size) doesn't do the right thing; it creates an unneccesary dynamic array copy in between, right? Or is DMD clever enought to optimize away the the dynamic array?

Comment: See also: http://forum.dlang.org/thread/ozicjxmzywyblevyauyr@forum.dlang.org#post-ozicjxmzywyblevyauyr:40forum.dlang.org

Comment: I don't think `.dup` copies are ever optimized. `.idup` is optimized away for arrays that are already immutable, however.